# How can I style simple form f.association check_boxes elements?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form, cloudinary, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to style a simple quiz. The image that I use is supposed be the background of the checkbox and the value.name should be on top (as a header) with the value.description as text below. Right now everything obviously is displayed next to each other. And I can't figure out a way to change it.

```
  <%= simple_form_for @user_value, :method => 'post' do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.association :value, label_method: lambda { |value| image_tag(cl_image_path value.photo.key) + "#{value.name} -  #{value.description}"} , :label => "Select at least 10 values", as: :check_boxes,  input_html: { class: "value-selector" }, item_wrapper_class: 'value-item'%>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Continue" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```